# How to add a value of an integer to a string in C

Tags: c

```
void F (char []);

int main( )
{
    int i = 2;
    F ("my number is %d",i)
}

void F (char c[])
{
    printf("%s",c);
    printf("\n");
}
```

- I'd like it to print "my number is 2".
- Please answer in the C language.

Comment: Google how to use [sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). *Please answer in the language c.* Can't I use English?

Comment: Note that your function prototype and your function do not match your function call.  So, please supply a [mcve]

Comment: 3. Do your homework yourself. Ask stack overflow only about a **specific problem**, following [ask].

Comment: @Olaf While I agree with you completely, I do wonder why you hestitate to go beyond commenting and do what needs to be done. Downvotes are much harder to ignore than critical comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is essentially a homework exercise.   If others answer, they are essentially rewarding a lack of effort.

Comment: @dandan78: So are close-votes. What is your point?

Comment: @Olaf Downvotes are much harder to ignore than closevotes, and  closevotes are maybe even easier to ignore than comments. Until there are five of them -- and there are rarely that many -- they're just a little gray number. Downvotes on the other hand send an unequivocal message.

Comment: @dandan78: "and there are rarely that many" - you should really have a look at the statistics. Anyway I don't see the point of your comments at all. I think I well know how this site works. Just leave it to me how I comment, CV, DV, UV, etc. If you want something relevant to say, feel free to ask on meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a string to pass to `F`. The [sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function is useful for this.

Here's an example:

```
int x = 10;
char buffer[128] = { '\0' };
sprintf(buffer, "The number is %d", i);
```

Now, `buffer` contains "The number is 10".

Answer (score 1):

You define `F` with only one input argument, yet you are passing to it two arguments: `"my number is %d"`, and `i`. This may feel natural because it's what you do when using the `printf` command, but it's actually contrary to what you know about defining functions. This is what you actually want

```
void F (const char* c, int i);

int main( ) {
    int i = 2;
    F ("my number is", i);
}

void F (const char* c, int i) {
    printf("%s %d\n", c, i);

}
```